# app running but not showing?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Made an application which targets .net 4 client.
Created an installer using Inno Setup and modified the script to look for and install .net 4 client if its missing. Installer works fine and .net does get installed.

My problem is that I installed my app on 2 PC's and I get the following issues.

PC 1 - App does not run and not even present in task manager.
PC 2 - App is running (visible in task manager) but won't display.

I created an installer using VS 2010 just so I could see the dependencies detected in case I'm missing a dll or something and sure enough I was. I rebuilt the Inno installer with the missing dll but I still have the same issue.

Is there anything I can do/look at to give an indication to the problem?

Comment: did you try to run your program as a standalone app? it would at least help you determine if the problem is in your program or in your installer.

Comment: Tried as a standalone app. Just ran the installer on the development PC and it runs fine. So I'm guessing something is missing

Comment: Don't you have any logging component? If not try one like log4net and check if something unusual comes up during startup of the app (e.g. any exceptions)

Comment: no I will have a look at log4net now, cheers for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Event Viewer to start with and see if that sheds light on why the application doesn't start.

Then the questions to ask are:

1. Does it run on the development machine, as an installed program not in VS2010?
2. Are all dependencies including non-NET ones installed?
3. Does it require any resources/dependencies at specific locations
   (are these hard coded literal paths rather than relative ones) and
   have these paths been created?
4. Being WPF does it use any Silverlight functionality? (This will need
   to be installed separately from .NET)
5. Has it been installed with the correct privileges?
6. Are there any data sources required, that haven't been set-up or
   can't be connected to when needed?
7. Is the application being prevented from running due to UAC (Vista,
   Windows 7) or anti-virus/firewall software?

Comment: The issue was that my application was using SQLCE 3.5 and it wasn't installed on the 2 pcs's.